# JS jquery replace multiple id attributes with values from array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays

A page has a table with rows which all have id attributes.

(starting with number instead of letter shouldn't cause problems here, since it doesn't have to be selected by CSS).

```
<tr id="0" class="whatever">
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
</tr>

<tr id="4" class="whatever">
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
</tr>

<tr id="2" class="whatever">
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
</tr>

<tr id="1" class="whatever">
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
</tr>

<tr id="3" class="whatever">
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
</tr>
```

We have a JS array which has exactly as many values as there are tr elements i.e. elements of the "whatever" class.

```
var arr=['0','1','2','3','4'];
```

How can I change all the tr id attributes to the ones of the arr array using jQuery or pure JS? The desired result should be:

```
<tr id="0" class="whatever">
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
</tr>

<tr id="1" class="whatever">
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
</tr>

<tr id="2" class="whatever">
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
</tr>

<tr id="3" class="whatever">
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
</tr>

<tr id="4" class="whatever">
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
</tr>
```

Just to make it clear: The elements don't have to be re-arranged on the page. The order and everything stays the same, but just the id values should get replaced.

I would do a forEach. But from there I have no idea how to proceed and couldn't find anything.

```
function ReplaceIDsFromArray(val, index) {
                    
  //do stuff
                    
}

arr.forEach(ReplaceIDsFromArray);
```

Or maybe first all tr or "whatever" elements have to be selected and put into an array, and perform the forEach on that?

Comment: @Sascha, look again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method and a `forEach` to replace your `id` with the `array` of `id's` numbers you have.

**Live Demo:**

```js
var arr = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'];

var getTds = document.querySelectorAll('.whatever') //get all tr's
//Loop over and replace
getTds.forEach(function(td, i) {
  td.id = arr[i] //replace current id's
});

//New IDs
let newIds = document.querySelector("table").innerHTML
console.log(newIds) //shows HTML with new ID's
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="0" class="whatever">
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="4" class="whatever">
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="2" class="whatever">
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="1" class="whatever">
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="3" class="whatever">
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate the array of identifiers and the table `rows` list in sync:

```js
function assignIdentifiers(rows, ids) {
    // Use `Math.min` to avoid out of range addressing
    let len = Math.min(ids.length, rows.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        rows[i].id = ids[i];
    }
}

// demo
let rows = document.querySelectorAll("table .whatever");
assignIdentifiers(rows, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
// Show result:
console.log(document.querySelector("table").innerHTML);
```

```html
<table>
<tr id="0" class="whatever">
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
</tr>

<tr id="4" class="whatever">
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
</tr>

<tr id="2" class="whatever">
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
</tr>

<tr id="1" class="whatever">
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
</tr>

<tr id="3" class="whatever">
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
</tr>
</table>
```